# How to get the object name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I print out the object Name "Student1" ?
Using Student1.constructor.name , I can only get "Student" but not "Student1"
Thank you!

```
function Student(aName, aCourse, idNumber, noOfQuiz){
    this.name = aName;
        this.courseCode = aCourse;
        this.studentID = idNumber;
    }

var Student1 = new Student("David", "FD201F", "12345678")
```

Comment: Very generally speaking that is not possible and neither should it be possible nor needed. What are you trying to achieve and why exactly? And how would you expect that to work? If you have to write `Student1.something` you already know and wrote the name of the variable and can just not do the extra work but stick with `Student1`.

Comment: Objects do not have names.  More than one reference can point to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

"Student1" isn't the *object*'s name (objects don't have names), it's the name of the the *variable* that refers to the object. You can't get that name from the object, not least because the same object can have more than one variable pointing at it:

```
var Student1 = new Student("David", "FD201F", "12345678");
var Student2 = Student1; // Both now point to the same object
```

In general, there's no reason to try to get the name of the variable. Instead, store any relevant information you need about the object on the object itself, or if you need to associate objects with names outside the object, use a `Map` or an object with a property (which has a name) that refers to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you could need this, because names are just references for the developer to access values..
You could do this instead:

```
var students = {};
students['student1'] = new Student("David", "FD201F", "12345678");
students['student2'] = new Student("Joe", "FFFFFF", "87654321");
```

then you can access to students keys like this:

```
Object.keys(students).forEach(key => console.log(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this, unless using some complicated stuff, like trying to access the memory and checking wich name  is related to the instance of each object.
using some sort of reflection. but it would be a nightmare